# Getting custom table data in customer dashboard for specific customer

Tags: magento2

**Block file**

```
<?php
    namespace vendor/module/Block;



    use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

    class Postform extends Template
    {

            protected $_connection;
            const CONFIG_CAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY = 'quickrfq/google_options/googlepublickey';
            const CONFIG_CAPTCHA_THEME = 'quickrfq/google_options/theme';
            const CONFIG_CAPTCHA_ENABLE = 'quickrfq/google_options/captchastatus';

            const CONFIG_FILE_EXT_UPLOAD = 'quickrfq/upload/allow';

        protected $scopeConfig;    
        public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource
        )
        {
            $this->scopeConfig = $context->getScopeConfig();
            $this->_connection = $resource->getConnection();
            parent::__construct($context);
        }

        public function getTableData()
        {    

        $myTable = $this->_connection->getTableName('fme_quickrfq');
        $sql     = $this->_connection->select()->from(
             ["tn" => $myTable]
        ); 
        $result  = $this->_connection->fetchAll($sql);
        return $result;
        }  


        public function getFormAction()
        {
            return $this->getUrl('quickrfq/index/post', ['_secure' => true]);
        }

        public function getCaptchaTheme()
        {

            $theme = $this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::CONFIG_CAPTCHA_THEME);
            return $theme;
        }

        public function isCaptchaEnable()
        {

            $enable = $this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::CONFIG_CAPTCHA_ENABLE);
            return $enable;
        }

        public function getAllowedFileExtensions()
        {

            $ext = $this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::CONFIG_FILE_EXT_UPLOAD);
            return $ext;
        }
        public function getPublicKey()
        {

            return $this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::CONFIG_CAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY);
        }
    }
```

**phtml file**

```
 <?php
    $blockObj= $block->getLayout()->createBlock('vendor\module\Block\Postform');
    print_r($blockObj->getTableData());

    ?>
```

**installschema.php**

```
<?php

namespace vednor\module\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;

class InstallSchema implements InstallSchemaInterface
{



    public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {


        $installer = $setup;
        $installer->startSetup();


        /**
                        * Create table 'quickrfq'
                */

        $table = $installer->getConnection()->newTable($installer->getTable('fme_quickrfq'))
                                ->addColumn(
                                    'quickrfq_id',
                                    \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
                                    null,
                                    ['identity' => true, 'unsigned' => true, 'nullable' => false, 'primary' => true],
                                    'Quickrfq ID'
                                )
                                ->addColumn(
                                    'company',
                                    \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                                    255,
                                    ['nullable' => true, 'default' => null],
                                    'Company'
                                )
                                ->addColumn(
                                    'contact_name',
                                    \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                                    255,
                                    [],
                                    'Contact Name'
                                )
                                ->addColumn(
                                    'phone',
                                    \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                                    255,
                                    [],
                                    'Phone'
                                )
                                ->addColumn(
                                    'email',
                                    \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                                    255,
                                    [],
                                    'Email'
                                )
                                ->addColumn(
                                    'project_title',
                                    \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                                    255,
                                    [],
                                    'Project Title'
                                )
                                ->addColumn(
                                    'date',
                                    \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_DATE,
                                    null,
                                    [],
                                    'Date'
                                )
                                ->addColumn(
                                    'budget',
                                    \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                                    255,
                                    [],
                                    'Budget'
                                )
                                ->addColumn(
                                    'overview',
                                    \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                                    255,
                                    [],
                                    'Overview'
                                )
                                ->addColumn(
                                    'prd',
                                    \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                                    255,
                                    [],
                                    'Prd'
                                )
                                ->addColumn(
                                    'status',
                                    \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                                    255,
                                    ['nullable' => false, 'default' => 'New'],
                                    'Status'
                                )
                                ->addColumn(
                                    'sku',
                                    \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                                    255,
                                    ['nullable' => false, 'default' => null],
                                    'sku'
                                )
                                ->addColumn(
                                    'create_date',
                                    \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP,
                                    null,
                                    ['nullable' => false, 'default' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TIMESTAMP_INIT],
                                    'Creation Date'
                                )
                                ->addColumn(
                                    'update_date',
                                    \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP,
                                    null,
                                    ['nullable' => false, 'default' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TIMESTAMP_INIT_UPDATE],
                                    'Update Date'
                                );


        $installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);

        $installer->endSetup();
    }
}
```

**result in customer dashboard under quote**
[image]

**explaination:-**

i have a custom module where am getting data from table and displaying it on customer dashboard under my quote tab. now with this block code it displays all the data available in table. what i want is to display the data of a customer by matching it with the email id he has signed in. means i want to show the data of customer whose email id match with email he has logged in. any advice on this will be a great help thanks

Comment: please check and update me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Use Model for custom table data manipulation**

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/Model**

**CustomerData.php**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Model;

use Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel;
use VendoreName\ModuleName\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerData as CustomerDataResourceModel;

class CustomerData extends AbstractModel
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init(CustomerDataResourceModel::class);
    }
}
```

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/Model/ResourceModel**

**CustomerData.php**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Model\ResourceModel;

use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb;

class CustomerData extends AbstractDb
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('fme_quickrfq', 'quickrfq_id');
    }
}
```

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/Model/ResourceModel/CustomerData**

**Collection.php**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerData;

use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection;
use VendoreName\ModuleName\Model\CustomerData as CustomerDataModel;
use VendoreName\ModuleName\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerData as CustomerDataResourceModel;

class Collection extends AbstractCollection
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init(
            CustomerDataModel::class,
            CustomerDataResourceModel::class
        );
    }
}
```

> And get your customer with matching email

```
protected $customerSession;
protected $CollectionData;


public function __construct(
    .............................................
    \VendoreName\ModuleName\Model\Session $customerSession,
    \VendoreName\ModuleName\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerData\CollectionFactory $CollectionData,
    .............................................
) {
    .............................................
    $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
    $this->CollectionData = $CollectionData;
    .............................................
}

public function getCustomerData()
{   
    // get current customer email 
    $customerEmail = $this->customerSession->getCustomer()->getEmail();

    //get custom table data
    $customerData = $this->CollectionData->create();
    $customerData->addFieldToFilter('email',$customerEmail);
    //print_r($customerData->getData());        

    return $customerData;
}
```

***I Hope This Helps You.***

Answer (score 0):

**Inject below class**

```
protected $customerSession;

public function __construct(
    ...................,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
    .................
) {
    parent::__construct(.......);
    $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
}
```

**Then modify your function getTableData()**

```
public function getTableData()
  {    
  $customerId = $this->customerSession->getCustomer()->getId();
    if(isset($customerId) && $customerId != ''){
        $customerEmail = $this->customerSession->getCustomer()->getEmail();
        $myTable = $this->_connection->getTableName('fme_quickrfq');
        $sql     = $this->_connection->select()->from(
             ["tn" => $myTable]
        )->where('tn.email? ',$customerEmail );
        $result  = $this->_connection->fetchAll($sql);
        return $result;
    }
    return;
}
```

make sure to change your column here, **tn.entity_id**  customerId column in your table "**fme_quickrfq**".

**Hope this may help you!!**

Comment: if(isset($customerId) && $customerId != '') can you please explain me this line

Comment: That line checks whether the customer is logged in or not, if logged in then it gets that customer data, else empty data will return, make a try with my code, it will work

Comment: no its not working coz i dnt have customer id field in my custom table

Comment: then is there any column in your custom table related to customer?

Comment: i want to match logged in customer email with email in table

Comment: that is what i have wrote in my question

Comment: @Pramod, please update your table structure, in the question, if you have email, then i will update my answer

Comment: see my installschema file in the question

Comment: check my updated answer!!

Comment: do i need to change my phtml file also

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105153/discussion-between-jafar-pinjar-and-pramod).

Comment: please check chat..